# Xcode Simulator enlarges the app then goes black

Tags: ios, xcode

Yesterday I built and launched my app on xcode and it ran no problem. Today I created a new branch, launched my project, built it, and when the simulator comes up, it just takes the app image, enlarges it until it covers the whole screen, then goes black.
When I clean the project and launch it, I get a cannot connect to pid error.
I have tried resetting the console, restarting my computer, google about the pid error, and cleaning the project.

I'm sorry I don't have more info than that but any other help would be greatly appreciated.

Jonah

Comment: "it just takes the app image, enlarges it until it covers the whole screen, then goes black." This is a crash, delete your application from the simulator and it should work when you deploy it again, you may have saved data that is not valid anymore and it causes a crash now because it's used when the application is launched.

Comment: Shouldn't resetting the content of simulator have done that? I deleted the app from it but I still get the issue when I run agian

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure about that.